# iOS URL settings shortcut doesn't launch into settings app

Tags: ios

(Yes I know using this url will result in Apple rejecting the app from App Store submission, however the intended use is not for an app released to the App Store).

I want to launch the user into the settings page with the silence unknown caller's switch, google results says this is the url to use for that:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "prefs:root=Phone&path=SILENCE_CALLS")!, options: [:])
```

However this doesn't work, it doesn't launch anything.
Is this the correct url, or might Apple have disabled this from functioning (I'm trying with iOS 16.4.1)

Comment: Including this url **will** result in Apple rejecting your submission, and these urls change from version to version. They are considered private api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From iOS 10+ versions code has changed, use below code.

You need to change `prefs:` to `App-Prefs:`

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=Phone&path=SILENCE_CALLS"];
[application openURL:URL options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
         NSLog(@"Opened url");
    }
}];
```